# Extracting all JavaScript filenames from a log file using bash script

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have 4 different named `log` files, all with `txt` extensions. I need to write a **bash**  script file that extracts JavaScript file names from any of these `log` files regardless of their names. The output of the script should **not** include the path, have to be unique, and sorted

After some research I came up with this:

```
cat logfile1.txt | grep '[^.(]*\.js' | awk -F " " '{print $7}' | sort | uniq -c| sort -nr
```

This code does only haft the job;

- PRO: It does extract any JS, `sorts` it, and gives `unique` results.

- CON: I need this in a file.sh not a command line as, it is now. Also, I'm getting the entire path to the JS file. I only need the file name `jquery.js`

I tried adding `grep -v "*/name-of-path-before-JS"` to block the result from giving me the full path but that isn't working.

I found someone who made something kind of similar using python;
[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60679909/extracting-all-javascript-filenames-from-a-log-file-using-python3)

```
filenames = set()

with open(r"/home/filelog.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        end = line.rfind(".js") + 3 # 3 = len(".js")
        start = line.rfind("/", 0, end) + 1 # 1 = len("/")
        filename = line[start:end]
        if filename.endswith(".js"):
            filenames.add(filename)


for filename in sorted(filenames, key=str.lower):
    print(filename)
```

Although is missing the `sort` and `uniq` options when giving the `output` it does give the results by only putting out `filename.js` and not the whole path as the command line I made. Also, I to add the path to the `log.txt` file while running the script and not just appended it as in the python script below.

Example;
$`./LogReaderScript.sh File-log.txt`

Comment: Can you provide a short example of log file? I'd like to know the `gap`
between the js filename and preceding string/character. If the js filename
always contains slashes, it will be preferable, because it will be easy to extract
the filename between the last slash and the extention `.js`.

Comment: @tshiono hi sure, here [Pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/DpxSSGe5) and yes all fines contain slashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the shell script `LogReaderScript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then                 # if no filenames are given
    echo "usage: $0 logfile .."         # then show the usage and abort
    exit 1
fi

grep -hoE "[^/]+\.js" "$@" | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

By setting the file as executable with `chmod +x LogReaderScript.sh`,
you can invoke:

```
./LogReaderScript.sh File-log.txt
```

If you want to process multiple files at a time, you can also say something
like:

```
./LogReaderScript.sh *.txt
```

- `-o` option to `grep` tells grep to print the matched substrings only,
  instead of printing the matched line.
- `-E` option specifies `extended regex` as a pettern.
- `-h` option suppresses the prefixed filenames on the output if multiple
  files are given.
- The pattern (regex) `[^/]+\.js` matches a sequence of any characters
  other than a slash, and followed by a extention `.js`. It will match
  the target filenames.
- `"$@"` is expanded to the filename(s) passed as arguments to the script.

Comment: this is perfect! is almost there, everything neat, the only thing that needs to be fix is `./t3.sh: 3: [[: not found`why am I getting that error? PS:t3.sh is the name of the script

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Some (older) `sh` may not support the `[[ .. ]]` expression. I have fixed the shebang line (the 1st line) to `bash`. How about now?

Comment: Ok, now it works. I will accept your post as the right answer because it did what it was supposed to do, find JS files. Although it didn't help me with my problem because is not being accepted by the server. But this is the right code for it. Thanks again.

Comment: ```Make a Bash script that extracts JavaScript file names from any access log file. `file1-log` file should be the first argument to this script. Make sure the file names DO NOT include the path, are unique, and are sorted. then run /challenge/access-log with your script's location as the first argument to get the flag.``` This is what I was supposed to do

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Can you elaborate about `not being accepted by the server`? What kind of error message does the serever output?

Comment: sure ```./file1-log  /home/student/t3.sh
Failed Test Case.
Make sure the filenames DO NOT include the path, are unique, and are sorted.
For more help, please check out the challenge description and hints.``` ./file1-log is a file that will be run against the one you helped make, and if everything went well, I should get a flag. But as you can see is not accepting it. the challenge and hints are those in my previous comment.

Comment: Hmm.. It's puzzling. It sounds like a false-positive of the code analyzer. You should probably ask your professor/instructor. Good luck.

Comment: ok, I found the problem and fixed it. I want to share it, in case someone else needs it. This is the code that works ```#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then              
    echo "usage: $0 logfile .."      
    exit 1
fi

grep -hoE "[^/]+\.js" "$@" | sort -u``` Once again, thank you @tshioso

Answer (score 1):

There's really no need to have a script as you can do the job with the oneliner, since you've mentioned you have multiple log files to parse i'm assuming this is a task you're doing on a regular basis.

In this case just define an alias in your `.bashrc` file with this oneliner:

```
cat $1 | awk '{print $7}' | grep '.js' | awk -F\/ '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq
```

Let's say you've created the alias `parser` then you'd just have to invoke `parser /path/to/logfile.log`

With the example logfile you've provided above, the output is:

```
➜  ~ cat logfile.txt | awk '{print $7}' | grep '.js' | awk -F\/ '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq
jquery.js
jquery.jshowoff.min.js
jshowoff.css
```

Explanation:

- `cat` is used to parse the file and then pipe the content into..
- `awk` which is extracting the 7th space separated field from the file, since those are apache access logs and you're searching for the requested file, the seventh field is what you need
- `grep` is extracting only the javascript files, ie. those ending with the `.js` extension
- `awk` is used again to print only the file name, we're defining a custom field separator this time with the `-F` flag, and executing the `print` command using the `$NF` argument which instructs `awk` to print only the last field
- `sort` and `uniq` are self explanatory, we're sorting the output then printing only the first occurrence for each repeated value.

`jquery.jshowoff.min.js` looked like bogus to me and i suspected i did something wrong with my commands, but it's an actual line (280) in your logfile

```
75.75.112.64 - - [21/Apr/2013:17:32:23 -0700] "GET /include/jquery.jshowoff.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 2553 "http://random-site.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPod; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A403 Safari/8536.25" "random-site.com"
```

Comment: first of all, Thank you for the help. The problem is that I really need the script. Using part of code I made this: ```for log in ${1,2,3,4,5}
do
echo $(cat $log |  awk '{print $7}' | grep '.js' | awk -F\/ '{print $NF}' | sort -u )
done```

Comment: Somehow it worked until an extent but is not only outputting JS files but anything with a js on it . this is the output of a log file ```AC_RunActiveContent.js ac_runactivecontent.js jquery.js jquery.jshowoff.min.js jquery.jshowoff2.js jquery.lightbox-0.5.js jshowoff.css phpmyadmin.css.php?lang=fr-iso-8859-1&convcharset=iso-8859-1&collation_connection=utf8_unicode_ci&token=6a401bcd8a8c2bdc08f856b421c42345&js_frame=right&nocache=3986415011 swfobject.js?ver=2.2```

Comment: OK, but using `grep "[^.(]*\.js"` instead of `grep ".js"` the script work perfectly. the only part that needs to be fixed is that the out put also gave me this file `swfobject.js?ver=2.2` how do I get rip of `?ver=2.2`